# ElasticSearch TermQuery find substring in _id field

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In elasticsearch I have data like this:

> _id: 14133095_IMP
>  _id: 54646546_OPS
>  ....

I would like to find all ids which contains IMP.

This is my mapping

```
@Id
private String id;
```

Here's my query

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("_id", "imp"))
                .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("sourceSystem", "smart"))
                .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("taskStatus", BpmConstants.ACTIVE_STATES.stream().map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

The problem is with first must clause. Without it will find a lot of records (including those without _imp). I would also like to filter records by _id only those which contains IMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Term` query in elasticsearch does exact matches therefore imp will not match 14133095_IMP. You need to use `match` query which does a full text search.
You can read more about these queries at

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: You point me right direction and this query works for me as intented .must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("_id", "*IMP"))